# UML State Diagram Difference between do and entry

Tags: state, uml, diagram

i really don't understand the difference between entry and do activities in UML state diagram

if i have state called create account and this state ask from user to enter his name,id and password

so enter name , id , password is entry activity or do activity ?

Comment: What is the issue? `enter` is performed when you enter the state. `do` is performed when you stay in the state (rather than exiting and performing the `exit` operation).

Comment: @qwerty_so i know that but i think i have conflict when i think about create account state when the user entering his information that means entry activity or do activity

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that the entry behavior is always run to completion, whereas the do behavior is only run to completion if no event triggers a transition. It will get interrupted by this event. Therefore, it could have an endless loop. If an effect-, do- or exit-behavior has such an endless loop, the statemachine will not react to events anymore.

As a sidenote: `create account` is not a good name for a state, since it contains an active verb. That is better suited for an activity. The state could be named `creating account`. The entry-behavior could be `create account` and this could include actions `enter name`, `enter id` and `enter password`. You should also model the possibility, that the users cancels the creation. Two completion transitions with guards `[account created]` and `[canceled]` could show what happens next.